# Idiomatic way to get model name by using table name

Tags: elixir, ecto

When reading `Ecto.schema.metadata` I found out that we can use model name to get the table for that model like this:

```
[
  Ecto.Schema.Metadata,
  nil,
  {nil, table_name},
  :built
] = Map.values(model_name.__struct__.__meta__)
```

My question is can we use table name to get the model of that table?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ use `%MyApp.Model{}.__struct__.__schema__(:source)` to query a table name for the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can fetch all modules of the app and find the one which has a `__schema__/1` function defined which returns the table name when called with `:source`:

```
table = "posts"

Application.spec(:my_app, :modules)
|> Enum.find(fn module ->
  function_exported?(module, :__schema__, 1) &&
    module.__schema__(:source) == table
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
MyApp.Post
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no explicit method to achieve that, but since we are in Elixir, everything is possible:

```rb
with {:ok, mods} <- :application.get_key(:my_app, :modules) do
  mods
  |> Enum.filter(fn mod ->
    try do
      apply(mod, :__schema__, [:source]) == "users"
    rescue
      e in UndefinedFunctionError -> false
    end
  end)
  |> hd()
end
#⇒ MyApp.User # OR `nil`
```

or, with more precise check:

```rb
with {:ok, mods} <- :application.get_key(:my_app, :modules) do
  mods
  |> Enum.filter(fn mod ->
    if apply(mod, :__info__, [:functions])[:__schemas__],
      do: apply(mod, :__schema__, [:source]) == "users"
  end)
  |> hd()
end
#⇒ MyApp.User # OR `nil`
```